# Apporoaches to solve the given algebraic expression

Tags: quadratics

If  $\displaystyle \ \  x^{4} \ +\ x^{2} \ =\ \frac{11}{5}$  then what is the value of the given expression

$$\displaystyle \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} +\ \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} \ =\ \ ?$$

My Try :

As I can find the value of $\displaystyle x$, from the given equation but it will be tedious I think !.

$$\displaystyle x^{4} \ +\ x^{2} \ =\ \frac{11}{5}$$

$$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow \ x^{2} +1/2 \ =\ \frac{7}{2\sqrt{5}}$$

$$\displaystyle \Longrightarrow \ x^2 \ =\  \ \frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}$$

Which is getting too much complicated to solve the expression by putting the value of $\displaystyle x$.

What could be the other way to solve the given expression?

Comment: Have you tried the substitution $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=y$ ?

Comment: @c-love-garlic yes i did, which is taking to the cubic expresion , I applied $a^3+b^3$ logic. But didnt succeed

Comment: Don't You mean $x=\pm \sqrt{\frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}}$?

Comment: @PeterMelech could you please explain a little bit your comment. My appologies I didn’t get it.

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora You computed correctly $x^2+\frac{1}{2}=\frac{7}{2\sqrt{5}}$, now to solve for $x$ You need to take the square root again...

Comment: @PeterMelech sorry I made a typo. But this approach is tedious to put in the expression

Comment: @GirishKumarChandora That's true, using $\frac{x+1}{x-1}=1+\frac{2}{x-1}$ and $\frac{x-1}{x+1}=1-\frac{2}{x+1}$ and $x=\sqrt{\frac{7-\sqrt{5}}{2\sqrt{5}}}$, I put the expression into wolfram alpha and got [this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%281%2B%282%2F%28sqrt%28%287-sqrt%285%29%29%2F%282sqrt%285%29%29%29-1%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29%2B%281-%282%2F%28sqrt%28%287-sqrt%285%29%29%2F%282sqrt%285%29%29%29%2B1%29%29%29%5E%281%2F3%29)

Comment: I'd just put it into the equation. Simple :)

Comment: It might be more tedious to find a fancy solution

Comment: If it aint broke, dont fix it

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$ a = \displaystyle \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} +\ \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}. $$
Notice that the first term is the multiplicative inverse of the second term. Thus
$$ a^3 = \displaystyle \frac{x+1}{x-1} + \frac{x-1}{x+1} + 3 \left(\displaystyle \left(\frac{x+1}{x-1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}} +\ \left(\frac{x-1}{x+1}\right)^{\frac{1}{3}}   \right). $$
So
$$ a^3 - 3 a =  \displaystyle \frac{x+1}{x-1} + \frac{x-1}{x+1}. $$
You can calculate the right hand side and then solve for $a$.

Comment: I also did this approach, as the equation will be cubic in terms of $a$ , which would again another task to solve the cubic expression for such typical number

Answer (score 1):

Let me try it

we have putting $t=\tan\Big(\frac{x_1}{2}\Big)$
$$\cos(x_1)=\frac{1-t^2}{1+t^2}$$

It's the [Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution)

Putting $y=t^2$ we get :

$$\cos(x_1)=\frac{1-y}{1+y}$$

Now we put $x=y$ to get :

$$\Big(-\cos(x_1)\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}+\Big(-\frac{1}{\cos(x_1)}\Big)^{\frac{1}{3}}=?$$

After that I have tried $\cos(3x)=4\cos^3(x)-3\cos(x)$.

Hope it helps (I think it's hard).

Answer (score 0):

Consider $A = (\frac{x+1}{x-1})^\frac{1}{3} + (\frac{x-1}{x+1})^\frac{1}{3}$ and $x = \tan u$. Since $x^4+x^2 = \frac{11}{5}$ then $\frac{\sin^2u}{(1-\sin^2u)^2}=\frac{11}{5}$ by solving a simple quadric equation we get that $\sin u = \pm \sqrt{\frac{27-7\sqrt5}{22}}$.
Therefore $A = (\frac{\tan u+1}{\tan u-1})^\frac{1}{3} + (\frac{\tan u+1}{\tan u-1})^\frac{1}{3}$ so from the tangent formula for adding two arc we get: $-A = \tan^\frac{1}{3} {(u+\frac{\pi}{4})}+ \cot^\frac{1}{3} {(u+\frac{\pi}{4})}$. By rasing both sides to 3 we get:$$3A-A^3=\pm\frac{1}{\sin(u+\frac{\pi}{4})\times\sqrt{1-\sin^2{(u+\frac{\pi}{4})}}}$$On the other hand we know: $\sin(u+\frac{\pi}{4})=\pm\frac{\sqrt {225\sqrt 5-280}}{11}$. By simplifications and solving a simple polynomial equation of third degree we can easily get the final answer.
I hope that it can help you. Thank you for your question.